# how to use XPO in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, devexpress

I am currently developing with Devexpress XAF framework, but the problem is that with windows form I have no idea how to use xpo, connect to the database, create views, ect .. exp of a simple application in WinForm:
  I would like to create a "Person" and "Operation" class
after having created these two classes, I don't know where to start.
how to proceed to be able to create this kind of application using xpo?
Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the XAF [Getting Started](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113577/getting-started) documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start from the [Bind the Data Model and User Interface](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/2256/getting-started/tutorial-1-your-first-data-aware-application-with-xpo#bind-the-data-model-and-user-interface) section of the [XPO Getting Started](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/2263/getting-started) Tutorial [1 - Your First Data-Aware Application with XPO](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/2256/getting-started/tutorial-1-your-first-data-aware-application-with-xpo) which demonstrates how to create a simple WinForms application that allows end-users to view and edit customer details.

Then you can continue with the [WinForms section](https://github.com/DevExpress/XPO/tree/master/Tutorials/WinForms/Classic) of the [DevExpress XPO ORM for .NET Framework / .NET Core / .NET Standard 2.0](https://github.com/DevExpress/XPO) repository
which explains how to create a simple XPO-based CRUD application using DevExpress components like data grid and data editors. 
Please also note that the [Tutorials](https://github.com/DevExpress/XPO/blob/master/Tutorials) subfolder of this repository contains CRUD samples and tutorials demonstrating how to use XPO in Console, WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET Core/MVC5/WebForms/Blazor or Xamarin apps.